# Importing a range of formulas from csv or txt file starts with ' in excel and sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, import

I am generating some image URLs with a python script and converting them to a formula. I have tried saving it to both a CSV and a TXT file as others suggested, but both lead to the same problem:

After importing or copying multiple lines all formulas in the edit mode start with `'`. I am unsure why that is. Copy-pasting just one line works as expected.

Here are some formulas if anybody wants to test this out.

```
=Image("https://resources.tidal.com/images/9b0a4cd9/0093/4668/8078/eebf4e18ce4e/1280x1280.jpg")
=Image("https://i.discogs.com/3hfDBeWAlfKQ__MA5bccufe68w0SAciLCpDK2EiDW5c/rs:fit/g:sm/q:90/h:400/w:394/czM6Ly9kaXNjb2dz/LWRhdGFiYXNlLWlt/YWdlcy9SLTEyMjgw/MjAwLTE1MzIwNTQ0/MTItOTMzNC5qcGVn.jpeg")
=Image("https://resources.tidal.com/images/874d0d17/8c99/455f/9919/f4e5c233dfd2/1280x1280.jpg")
=Image("https://resources.tidal.com/images/8fa28feb/627c/4b1c/8d74/60709de9a126/1280x1280.jpg")
=Image("https://resources.tidal.com/images/1b853597/595f/4c9d/a683/eb2976626e30/1280x1280.jpg")
```

Formulas in Sheet starting with '=Image:
[image: Formulas in Sheet starting with '=Image]